# mongoose/mongo insert multiple elements into sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert multiple items into sub document using mongoose:

```
User.update(
   {'_id': userId, 'pages._id': pageId},
   { $push:
      {'pages.$.items':
          { $each: data }
      }
   }, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result); // prints { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
   }
);
```

What am I doing wrong? It't neither throwing an error nor inserting any item.

Edit: User schema:

```
var PageSchema= new Schema({
    items: [{
        a: String,
        b: String
    }]
});
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    pages: [PageSchema]
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I'm able to insert 1 item using this code:

```
User.findOne({'_id': userId, 'page._id': pageId}).exec(function(err, user) {
    user.pages.id(pageId).items.push(data[0]);
    user.save();
});
```

but I guess it's not good approach for inserting multiple elements.

Comment: Schema is correct because I can manually insert item using mongoose user.pages.id(pageId).items.push(data[0]) and then save it using user.save()

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `User` model's schema definition?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: I've tried the above in mongo shell, works ok. Even the results show that there is a modified document [`{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult.nModified). Perhaps you meant to return the modified document? If so, use [`User.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with the `{ 'new': true }` option.

Comment: Yeah, I know the result is fine that's why I don't know why it doesn't work. findOneAndUpdate works though but I don't need to return anything so update fits better.. It's some mongoose bug(feature) on update..Feel free to post it as an answer, Ill google more about new: true for update function.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Have the same problem